# Font loaders must be called and assigned to a const in the module scope on Nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, fonts

Am trying to load google font to Nextjs project but I'm getting the error below. In nextjs12 It works okay but I have to use the link for the fonts in the head. This error occurs also using @next/font/local.

I've struggled with this and any help is appreciated.

Am using the official docs process for adding global fonts. Am on Nextjs13.

My _app.tsx code is:

```
import { useApollo } from "@api/apollo/apolloclient";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { CacheProvider, EmotionCache } from "@emotion/react";
import { Ubuntu } from "@next/font/google";

import "focus-visible/dist/focus-visible";

import { DefaultSeo } from "next-seo";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";

import { ChakraProvider, ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/react";

import theme from "@definitions/chakra/theme";
import { ThemeColorProvider } from "@definitions/context/theme";
import createEmotionCache from "@definitions/utils/createEmotionCache";

import Layout from "@layouts/default";

import "@styles/app.css";
import "@styles/global.scss";

import SEO from "../../next-seo.config";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

type ComponentWithPageLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: AppProps["Component"] & {
    PageLayout?: React.ComponentType;
  };
  emotionCache: EmotionCache;
};

const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

function sApp({
  Component,
  emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache,
  pageProps,
}: ComponentWithPageLayout): JSX.Element {
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps);
  const AnyComponent = Component as any;
  const Layoutio = Component.PageLayout as any;

  const ubt = Ubuntu({
    weight: ["300", "400", "500", "700"],
    style: ["normal", "italic"],
  });

  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setShowChild(true);
  }, []);

  if (!showChild) {
    return null;
  }

  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return <></>;
  } else {
    return (
      <>

      <style jsx global>{`
          html {
            font-family: ${ubt.style.fontFamily};
          }
        `}</style>

        <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
          <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
            <ThemeColorProvider>
              <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
                <ColorModeScript
                  initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode}
                />
                <DefaultSeo {...SEO} /> 
                {Component.PageLayout ? (
                  <Layoutio>
                    <AnyComponent {...pageProps} />
                  </Layoutio>
                ) : (
                  <Layout>
                    <AnyComponent {...pageProps} />
                  </Layout>
                )}
              </ChakraProvider>
            </ThemeColorProvider>
          </ApolloProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: I only have this issue when using an experimental SWC plugin. I filed a minimal repro bug here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44433

Comment: Did you find the solution @frattaro?

Comment: No :( We're on AWS Amplify, and amplify is struggling to keep up with the changes in next so i'm stuck on a not-latest version. I'm pretty confident the solution will require changes in next to fix and I just keep checking if they've fixed in latest. The plugin that's more necessary than this is the code-coverage one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under _app.tsx the minimal code that worked is shown below. Am using chakra. The downside is that this is experimental and worked on some devices and failed on some like Safari.

```
import { useApollo } from "@api/apollo/apolloclient";
import { EmotionCache, CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import { Ubuntu } from "@next/font/google";

import "focus-visible/dist/focus-visible";

import { DefaultSeo } from "next-seo";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";

import theme from "@definitions/chakra/theme";
import { ThemeColorProvider } from "@definitions/context/theme";
import createEmotionCache from "@definitions/utils/createEmotionCache";

import "@styles/app.css";
import "@styles/global.scss";

import SEO from "../../next-seo.config";
import { ChakraProvider, ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";

type ComponentWithPageLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: AppProps["Component"] & {
    PageLayout?: React.ComponentType;
  };
  emotionCache: EmotionCache;
};

const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

function sApp({
  Component,
  emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache,
  pageProps,
}: ComponentWithPageLayout): JSX.Element {
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps);
  const AnyComponent = Component as any;
  const Layoutio = Component.PageLayout as any;

  const ubt = Ubuntu({
    weight: ["300", "400", "500", "700"],
    style: ["normal", "italic"],
  });

  return (
    <>
      <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
        <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
          <ThemeColorProvider>
            <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
              <ColorModeScript
                initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode}
              />
              <DefaultSeo {...SEO} />
               //Wrap component with classname
              <main className={ubt.className}>
                <AnyComponent {...pageProps} />
              </main>
            </ChakraProvider>
          </ThemeColorProvider>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For next config add this block in nextconfig.

```
  experimental: {
appDir: true,
fontLoaders: [ 
  { loader: "@next/font/google", options: { subsets: ["latin"] } },
],},
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply move the ubt constant above the sApp function :)

Comment: This did not work , for some reason font loader is being compiled as var and not as const

Comment: Same for me did you found the solution to this problem?

Comment: @giles I've posted what worked for me below.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me since this needs to be a constant moving it outside of the main App function worked.

Answer (score 3):

just use it outside the function for example

```
const myFont = localFont({
    src: 'local src',
    display: 'fallback',
});

function myApp() {
  return <div className={myFont.className}></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too, But here is my solution .

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Butterfly_Kids } from '@next/font/google';
import Button from "../Button";
```

```
const inter = Butterfly_Kids({ weight: "400", subsets:["latin-ext" ] })
```

You  have to specify some properties to your font function object e.g,

```
Butterfly_Kids({
 weight: "400",
 subsets:["latin-ext" ],
style : "normal
 })
```

etc
I hope this solve your problem.